# Passing form data between views with image field

Tags: python, django-forms, django-views

I have a form that contain an image field. Before submitting the form, I want user to be redirected to a preview page, where he can submit the form or go back to the previous view and do some changes. I don't want the form to be saved in database before accepting the preview. 
The problem is that I don't know how to correctly pass the form between views with no commiting it. I tried to do it using sessions, but there was a PickleError (caused because of the image field probably) when I was passing whole form. Then, I tried to pass form.cleaned_data to the session variable but then I don't know how to save it to the database in the next step. Any ideas?

```
temp = request.session['form_cleaned']
form = Form(instance=temp)
```

doesn't work

View 1, part of it

```
form = AdForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save(commit=False)
    request.session['form_cleaned'] = form.cleaned_data
```

View 2:

```
def another_view(request):
    temp = request.session['form_cleaned']
    form = Form()
    # what should i do here?
    if form.is_valid():
        form.site = Site.objects.get_current()
        form.user = request.user
        ad = form.save()
        return render(request, 'finish_template.html')
```